# PHP Capitalize each word and after bracket with special characters

Tags: php, string, uppercase, lowercase, capitalize

I have a script to convert uppercase to lowercase, but capitalize first letter of each word. Also I want to capitalize the forst letter after a bracket. The code works, but not with special norwegian characters. Have a look at my code;

```
<?php
$text= "BIG LETTERS WITH ÆØÅØÆØÅØÆ (MORE ÆØÆÅØ HERE)";
echo mb_convert_case($text, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
?>
```

This outputs;

```
Big Letters With (More Here)
```

As you can see, the special norwegian characters are removed. How can I keep those characters and make sure that all first letter of a word get capitalized, and the rest is lowercase? It's important to me that the first letter after a bracket is capitalized too.

Comment: "the special norwegian characters" have you set the correct charset?

Comment: If I set charset to ISO-8859-1 it will display the special characters as black diamonds with a questionmark in it. I get the string from a XML file, so there is no way for me to change the input from the XML file.

Comment: you need to just convert string ??

Comment: @zorensen you can use `ucwords`

Comment: @zorensen no just use `ucwords($text)`

Comment: @Abdulla I've tried this code;

    $temp1 = ucwords(mb_strtolower($xml->LogEvents->LogEvent->AssetEvent->Asset->Artist['Name'], 'UTF-8'));
    $temp2 = ucwords(mb_strtolower($xml->LogEvents->LogEvent->AssetEvent->Asset['Title'], 'UTF-8'));

    $line1 = preg_replace("/(\w+)/e","ucfirst('\\1')", $temp1);
    $line2 = preg_replace("/(\w+)/e","ucfirst('\\1')", $temp2);

This WORKS! However, this will capitalize any special character in the middle of a word and that looks really strange.

Comment: can't you just convert all to lowercase (strtolower), then ucwords?

Comment: hmm.. I could, but would that capitalize all first letters after brackets and hyphens?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `ucwords()` function to achieve this.

```
$text= "BIG LETTERS WITH ÆØÅØÆØÅØÆ (MORE ÆØÆÅØ HERE)";
echo str_replace('( ', '(', ucwords(str_replace('(', '( ', strtolower($text))));
```

Comment: Great! This works somehow, however, the first letter after the bracket doesn't get capitalized. Your code outputs; Big Letters With Æøåøæøåøæ (more Æøæåø Here)

The "m" after the first bracket doesn't get capitalized.

Comment: That works great! How about hyphens? If the string is this;
$text= "BIG LETTERS WITH ÆØÅØ-ÆØÅØÆ (MORE ÆØÆÅØ HERE)";

The first word after the hyphen will still be lowecase.